# Power BI: Import mode - Alternate credentials not working

Tags: powerbi, windows-authentication, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Power BI.

I'm trying to connect to the server (Analysis Services) with import mode, using alternate credentials (*domain\user*). Unfortunately, there is a error: *'We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again*'

The credentials I'm provided are valid and correct.

I also tried it with other usernames, who have access to the server, but there is the same error. The error is also present for my other colleagues.

I've searched Internet and the solutions provided here are not working in this case. The server allows remote connections and I cannot open Power BI as administrator (it's a company's laptop).

Could you please advise some other solution?

Comment: could you please share the solutions you've tried so far?

Comment: No real solution, as I have no idea for solution and couldn't find anything helpful at any forums. Just tried different usernames that should have access to the server, try it on different laptops and check if the server allows remote connections in MSSql.